# In game replay system doesn't work correctly when animations are used on a character

Tags: unity, c#, replays

I have created an in game replay system that essentially just stores each object's position and rotation at each FixedUpdate(). Once an even is triggered, the replay is then played back using FixedUpdate() as well. Each player has a character that is named based on their Google Play username. The GameObject for that character then has a child called "Components" which is acted upon by an animation whenever it is triggered. This is where the replay gets thrown off. For some reason when the animation is triggered, the replay is not captured as it should be. It is as if the animation never happened in the replay and then once the game scene is reset after the replay, the character is facing an awkward direction.

Basically a player can trigger an even that makes their character flip. The animation is what handles the flip. The animation manipulates the "Components" GameObject of the character. I keep track of the position/rotation of both the character's parent GameObject as well as the "Components" GameObject in order to keep everything exactly the way it was stored, yet it is incorrect somehow.

Here is the code I use to store my positions and rotations for each player:

```
static Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]> positions = new Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]>();
static Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]> rotations = new Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]>();
static Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]> compPositions = new Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]>();
static Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]> compRotations = new Dictionary<GameObject, Vector3[]>();
static int index = 0;
public static int positionFillLength = 0;

public void StorePositions(GameObject[] chars)
{
    Transform component = null;
    bool nullVals = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == null || chars[i].name == "NotSet") continue;
        if (chars[i] != null)
        {
            nullVals = false;
            foreach (Transform comp in chars[i].transform)
            {
                if (comp.name == "Components")
                    component = comp;
            }
            if (!positions.ContainsKey(chars[i]) && !rotations.ContainsKey(chars[i]))
            {
                positions.Add(chars[i], new Vector3[10800]);
                rotations.Add(chars[i], new Vector3[10800]);
                compPositions.Add(chars[i], new Vector3[10800]);
                compRotations.Add(chars[i], new Vector3[10800]);
            }
            positions[chars[i]][index] = chars[i].transform.position;
            rotations[chars[i]][index] = chars[i].transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            compPositions[chars[i]][index] = component.transform.position;
            compRotations[chars[i]][index] = component.rotation.eulerAngles;
        }
    }

    if (!nullVals)
    {
        positionFillLength++;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Here is the code used to play the replay:

```
public void PlayReplay(int index, GameObject[] chars)
{
    Transform component = null;
    foreach (var obj in positions)
    {
        if (obj.Key.name == "NotSet") continue;
        if (Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key) > -1)
        {
            if (!chars[Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key)].activeSelf)
            {
                chars[Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key)].SetActive(true);
            }
            if (positions[obj.Key][index] != Vector3.zero)
            {
                chars[Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key)].transform.position = positions[obj.Key][index];
                chars[Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key)].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotations[obj.Key][index]);
                foreach (Transform comp in chars[Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key)].transform)
                {
                    if (comp.name == "Components")
                        component = comp;
                }
                component.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(compRotations[obj.Key][index]);
                component.position = compPositions[obj.Key][index];
            }
            else
            {
                chars[Array.IndexOf(chars, obj.Key)].SetActive(false);
                Game.playingReplay = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**6/21/16**

I have continued testing with this and I noticed something very odd. My game is a real time multiplayer game, so when I test in real time with multiple players, the animations are shown just fine...just not in the replay. That means that the rotation of the "component" Transform is not being applied or saved correctly. This makes it even more odd as I seem to be using the same idea as the replay system, but this works and the replay system does not. The only difference is I am using an Interpolation in order to smooth the character movements over the network:

```
foreach (var player in players)
{
    if (player.ParticipantId != myPlayer.ParticipantId)
    {
        if (player.InterpolationDestPosition != Vector3.zero && player.InterpolationDestRotation != Vector3.zero && player.InterpolationComponentDestRotation != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Transform component = null;
            foreach (Transform comp in player.character.transform)
            {
                if (comp.name == "Components")
                    component = comp;
            }
            float pctDone = (Time.time - player.InterpolationUpdateTime) / .16f;
            if (pctDone <= 1f)
            {
                player.character.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(player.InterpolationStartPosition, player.InterpolationDestPosition, pctDone);
                player.character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.Euler(player.InterpolationStartRotation), Quaternion.Euler(player.InterpolationDestRotation), pctDone);
                component.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.Euler(player.InterpolationComponentStartRotation), Quaternion.Euler(player.InterpolationComponentDestRotation), pctDone);
            }
            else player.character.transform.position = character.transform.position + (player.LastKnownVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to me that this interpolation over the network results in rotations that are visible...but the replay system is more simple but uses the same idea, yet it doesn't work.

Is the question not clear enough? Do I need to explain something a little more thoroughly?

Comment: So when you replay, none of the animations happen? What triggers the animation? Presumably you are not replaying whatever triggered the animation.

Comment: @milk Animations are triggered by each player in game. I don't need to play back whatever triggers the animation because the animation is on part of the character that I keep the rotation for, so when the replay is played back it plays through the saved rotations.